# How to connect to local running services from GitHub Codespaces opened in local VSCode?

Tags: github, portforwarding, codespaces, github-codespaces

I'm currently working on a project that utilizes Redis and RabbitMQ, both of which are running locally on their default ports. I've opened this project in GitHub Codespaces but through my local VSCode instance. My objective is to run my project in Codespaces while still connecting to the services(i.e Redis,RabbitMQ ) running on my localhost.

I attempted port forwarding as suggested in some resources, but it appears that it exposes services from the Codespaces environment to the outside world, which is the opposite of what I want. I'm looking to access services from my local environment within the Codespaces session.

I tried port forwariding. Aftter adding port 5672 on which my redis instance is running. It gives me forwarded Address `127.0.0.1:36751` which doesn't seem to be expected result.